justify-items не выравнивает разделённые тегом br текстовые узлы
Если каждая строка обёрнута в span, то всё работает правильно, а если переносы строк сделаны через br, то весь текст центрируется единым куском. По идее br - это тег, а значит каждая строка должна обрабатываться как отдельный айтем, но почему-то этого не происходит.
Почему так и как исправить?


p {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}
<p>
  <span>1234567890</span>
  <span>1234567890 1234567890</span>
  <span>1234567890</span>
</p>

<p>
  1234567890<br>
  1234567890 1234567890<br>
  1234567890
</p>

<p>
  1234567890<span></span>
  1234567890 1234567890<span></span>
  1234567890
</p>




А вам не кажется что это логично?

Нет. Flex и grid считают текстовые ноды своими айтемами (впрочем, последовательные текстовые ноды объединяются в один айтем), но br - это тег, а значит я ожидаю, что он разделяет ноды. Добавил в пример аналогичный код, но вместо <br> стоит <span></span> всё так же между нодами - в таком варианте всё работает ожидаемым образом.
PS: Надо для этого.

А вам не кажется что это логично? Justify-items действует только на элементы (items) внутри grid. А текст все items должен выравниваться с помощью text-align например.

@AndreiFedorov, нет, не кажется. Дополнил вопрос, почему именно.

"br" is not friendly with the flexbox?

@Grundy, оно.. Но фиксов не видно...

@Qwertiy, по идее их и нет, потому что особенность конкретно тега br

@Grundy, ну если верить в br { content: '\A'; display: contents; white-space: pre; }, то по идее должно помогать изменение display или appearence, но они оба ничего не делают, а хрому помогает изменение content...

Не знаю, почему, но помогает (как оказалось, в FF не работает):
br {
  content: "";
}



p {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}

br {
  content: "";
}
<p>
  <span>1234567890</span>
  <span>1234567890 1234567890</span>
  <span>1234567890</span>
</p>

<p>
  1234567890<br>
  1234567890 1234567890<br>
  1234567890<br>
</p>




В ff не работает этот способ.

@AndreiFedorov, действительно, в FF не работает. Поигрался с FF - не знаю, как его заставить получить желаемый результат.

Всё дело в том, что br создаёт переполнение по ширине, когда текст сам переходит на следующую строку, когда как обычный текст переходит на следующую строку только когда достигнет конца внешнего элемента.
А у flex центрирование идёт элементов, а не текста внутри элемента и пока элемент не достиг максимальной ширины внешнего контейнера, он центрирует, а как только достигнет максимальной ширины, перестаёт этот закон действовать и поэтому когда центрируете текст внутри flex элемента, лучше всегда писать text-align: center на случай перехода текста на следующую строку.
В примере ниже я сделал второй блок со span, но сделал переполнение по ширине и как видите он себя ведёт так же как и br. Просто как в начале писал span упёрся в ширину внешнего элемента и создал вторую строку, а br сам создал вторую строку игнорируя внешнюю ширину.


p {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
<p>
  <span>1234567890</span>
  <span>1234567890 1234567890</span>
  <span>1234567890</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span>1234567890</span>
  <span>1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890</span>
  <span>1234567890</span>
</p>

<p>
  1234567890<br>
  1234567890 1234567890<br>
  1234567890
</p>

<p class="centered">
  1234567890<br>
  1234567890 1234567890<br>
  1234567890
</p>





br не создаёт переполнение по ширине - наоборот, его создаёт автоматический перенос, а не ручной. Проверятся вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/aj84ohn0/. 2. Если бы там было "переполнение по ширине", элемент бы растянулся на всю ширину вообще безо всякого центрирования: https://i.sstatic.net/YSEYiax7.png, а сейчас он стоит в середине как единый айтем. Даже в твоём примере видно, что текстовый узел и спан разного размера и внутри спана есть пустота справа. PS: А ps никто не читает...


@Qwertiy мда, и что в примере вашем я должен был понять? Я то же самое вывел и привёл примеры разные. А вы вывели просто два переполнения, одно при помощи br, а второе по ширине divа. Я это если что описал. Вы там даже flex не поставили, что там по вашему должно было меняться? Вы даже не переполненные по ширине тексты не добавили, как вы хотели показать центрирование? И ещё в доказательство, что br сам создал переполнение по ширине видно в вашем примере, так как вы не поставили min-width. Вы вообще поняли смысл задачи этой? Я всё правильно написал.

На ширину смотри. При переносе по br ширина идёт по контенту без дорполнительного расширения, а при автоматическом переносе по контенту div расширяется до полного размера. Flex там и не при чём - так всегда работает. Мог inline-block поставить, но поставил float.

@Qwertiy считай как хочешь, нет времени объяснять тебе, на досуге просто сядь и почитай внимательно, что я написал и обмысли хорошо.
